# Change window registry value using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS to change value of window registry for informix

[image]

When I try to execute this process task , getting error , the process exit code is 1 while the expected was 0

The above command running fine in cmd and successfully update the value

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the error by opening the visual studio as a administrator and executing the package.
Basically it was getting access denied issue and running as a admin solved it